# Changing YYYYDDMM_rest_of_filename.xls to YYYYMMDD_rest_of_filename.xls in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an enormous amount of excel files formatted as: YYYYDDMM_rest_of_filename.xls

How could I change them all using ruby in the less number of commands possible to YYYYMMDD_rest_of_filename.xls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch them:

```
str = "20103109_rest_of_filename.xls"

str[4,2], str[6,2] = str[6,2], str[4,2]
p str #=> "20100931_rest_of_filename.xls"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go file by file and run a regexp on the filename capturing
the YYYY, DD, MM, _rest_of_filename groups.

Once you have the groups it's easily to concatenate strings 
and rename the file with the rename function in the File class.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
file_name = '20113009_report.xls'
file_name.sub!(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.+)/, '\1\3\2\4' )
p file_name  # "20110930_report.xls"
```